# ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I am trying to install node packages on my windows machine using npm from a fresh install of node.

however, I am getting ETIMEDOUT errors. I checked few other stackoverflow questions with similar problem and almost all of them are related to problems when behind a proxy. Same is not the case with me. My system is not behind any proxy server. Can someone help me with resolving it.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> npm -v
2.5.1
PS C:\windows\system32> npm install bower -g
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i
nstall" "bower" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you completely, utterly, 100% certain you are not behind a proxy? Are you sure in the same way that your system is not configured to use a proxy? Perhaps only npm is configured to use a proxy...? Check `npm config list`.

Comment: I was able to solve this. I was actually not behind a proxy, but somehow the proxy parameter got set in npm config. I was able to solve the issue by using following command : npm config delete proxy

Comment: I have the same problem.  How do you find out where it's actually trying to connect to?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I turned out that Google One's VPN was causing this. Turning it off resolved it.

Comment: I had this problem when Docker was running some another process on my machine. I just restarted my MacBook and it worked.

Answer (score 59):

I am posting this answer in case some one faces the same issue.

I was able to solve this by running following command:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and this fixed it for me.  Interestingly, it was only the "npm install" run in an application folder that was failing. I ran "npm install -g gulp" with no problems. I'm a noob to node though so don't know if that's to be expected.

Comment: You're worthy. Go get your mjonir

Comment: Really helped me buddy u make my day

Comment: I do not understand it. If I am behind proxy, I still need to use proxy to get the packages from npm, right?

Answer (score 23):

First, run
 `npm config list` 
and check whether you are behind a proxy. If so, try running

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

as required

**If this method did not work, reinstall nodejs.

Comment: Worked for me! 

Comment: I ran this command, but how do I understand from my output that whether I am behind a proxy or not?

Answer (score 18):

If removing the npm proxy config settings (or correctly setting them, if that is necessary for you) did not fix it, then [This](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4163) github issue discusses what might be happening. My summary is that for some reason the ipv6 dns resolution to the registry is not resolving correctly and seems to be randomly failing for people.

My command was fetching from `registry.npmjs.org` using npm 9.1.2 and node 18.12.1 - I was running this from a windows terminal via vscode.

I ended up disabling ipv6 via the network properties of my adapter [see here](https://networking.grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=17573)

Again, changing the npm config proxy settings did not resolve anything for me. I re-enabled ipv6 after my command finished.

Answer (score 12):

Not on Windows but it can help there as well.

Node 16 worked, Node 18 did not. Turns out it was related to IPv6. As soon as I disabled IPv6 the connection did not timeout any more. The target registry was a Nexus server.

Comment: This is the only thing in this list of answers that actually worked for me. Unsure the implications of turning ipv6 off, so I turned it back on after running my npm command.

Comment: If you don't want to disable IPv6 on your system, you can use a flag to fix this issue. In linux, I set up a command like this: `alias npm-ipv4="node --dns-result-order=ipv4first $(which npm)"` then I can do `npm-ipv4 ping` to confirm it works, and do `npm-ipv4 install ...`

Answer (score 8):

I tried all the suggested solutions I could find on GitHub forums and StackOverflow topics. Finally **disabling my router's firewall** solved the issue immediately.

I am using Windows 10, node 4.0.0 and npm 2.13.4.

Comment: Thanks! Disabled IPv4 SPI firewall setting on a Linksys router, and suddenly `npx` commands worked.

Answer (score 8):

First see the npm config list:

```
npm config list
```

If you don't find `http-proxy`, `https-proxy` and `proxy correctly` set, then
You need to configure npm to work with your web proxy. For example:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080 
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080 
npm config set http-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Comment: I have no idea WHY, but THIS works! Merci beacoup!
P.S. My npm broke after I installed Hamachi, maybe it's somehow connected

Answer (score 5):

You can try to throttle the number of simultaneous connections with the following command (for example 3 maximum simultaneous connections):

```
npm set maxsockets 3
```

The CLI has been allowing this option since npm@3.8.0. The default is 50 simultaneous connections max. See [this link](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/5b4e3f3caff1f7ed30281b0b450de056a817bbc5/CHANGELOG.md#limit-concurrent-requests) for further reference.

Answer (score 5):

If it's not proxy, the issue might be with IPv6. Check:

```bash
ping -4 registry.npmjs.org # does IPv4 connect?
ping -6 registry.npmjs.org # does IPv6 connect?
npm ping # alternative command
```

If the issue is that only IPv6 is not working (could be e.g. your ISP's fault), then you can use node flag `--dns-result-order=ipv4first` to make npm prefer IPv4:

```bash
node --dns-result-order=ipv4first /path/to/npm
```

This is useful if you don't want to disable IPv6 or change network settings on your system.

In Ubuntu, I had first set up a command like this on `~/.bash_aliases`:

```bash
alias npm-ipv4="node --dns-result-order=ipv4first $(which npm)"
```

Then I could do `npm-ipv4 ping` to confirm it works, and use it normally, like `npm-ipv4 install ...` if regular npm doesn't work because of an IPv6 issue.

However, when trying to update node, it wasn't enough because `node` was being run from some script during the update, without the flag. So, instead, I made an executable `node` script with PATH precedence (e.g. `~/.local/bin/node`), which calls node with the flag, like:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
node=/path/to/node # e.g. /usr/bin/node or $NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX/bin/node
$node --dns-result-order=ipv4first "$@"
```

Then I can just use it normally like `npm i -g node`, etc.

Comment: This it!! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

If you have internet filter turns out it was related to it.
I found out that the problem was because of it (when I didn't have internet filter, the npm commands worked perfectlly) the reason is that they use 'proxy'.

Nothing helped me because I was not behind 'proxy', -
Then i diabled **ipv6** and it worked.

To Disable IPv6 in Windows 11 you can use this guide:
https://www.itechguides.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-11/ .

BTW, If you disable IPv6 on your computer, you might lose access to IPv6-only websites. Also, you might lose some network management advantages as well. So you can just enable ipv6 again right after you run the command you need..

Answer (score 2):

For people working in corporates (where you cannot delete or edit the proxy configuration of the organization):

There must be an `.npmrc` file in your users folder. If not, you can create one. This file can be edited to register the proxy settings of your organization. Contact your organization's IT team to get the relevant proxy details.

Example of the `.npmrc`file contents for my organization:

```
strict-ssl=false
registry=https://nexus.com/nexus/content/groups/npm-read/
proxy=http://primary-proxy.gslb.intranet.com:8080/
https-proxy=http://primary-proxy.gslb.intranet.com:8080
```

This file can be found in your users folder:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to install any packages before because of this error then after 1 hour, I finally resolved it because I was not behind a proxy but the proxy parameters got set in the npm config thats why that error was showing.

I'am posting it because if anyone is facing the same issue and if they are not behind any proxy then they can use the following commands:-

npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy

npm config delete http-proxy

npm config delete https-proxy

set HTTP_PROXY=null

set HTTPS_PROXY=null

Answer (score 2):

If none of the mention solutions works for you then, try switching your node version.

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve this is to set Fiddler as your proxy server.  This probably only works for windows.

Running Fiddler, type these commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://localhost:8888

npm config set https-proxy http://localhost:8888
```

Before you do this, Rules -> Automatically Authenticate

Answer (score 1):

First, check for environment variables and use following command to remove proxy:

```bash
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

use these commands and then change the network like change wifi network to mobile data or any other I spent a lot of time then resolve by this method

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solution worked for me and I ended up updating npm's version which worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34400216)

Answer (score 1):

I connected to my work VPN and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
npm config set proxy null
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same error. the root cause was the proxy settings : there are several answers provided in here to reset the proxy but none of them worked for me.
Below commands solved my problem, give them a try.

```
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: This looks like two commands - can you edit to clean up formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement all solutions and suggested commands for npm and yarn but it's not resolved.

When I disable my VPN and try to "yarn install, " it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

After all the effort with no result, I reboot my router and it works!

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10, adding Node.js to the firewall authorized applications AND restarting the laptop solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing to a different network seemed to fix it. Maybe the router has certain proxy settings that timeouts npm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This was a wired solution, but in my case just turn off/on the wifi, resolved the issue.
Really extrange, since I was googling the solution, so I had internet conexion

Answer (score -1):

I also face this issue

**Solution**

1. Just uninstall Node.js .
2. uninstall its package also which you downloaded from website.
3. Download Node.js from website.
4. Reinstall Node.js .

It will Work.