# npm doesn't download packages (connect ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: node.js, proxy, npm

For some reason my npm stopped working with network suddenly.

I didn't really get why, so I decided to look through the stackoverflow questions but all the answers I could find were about running npm behind `corporate` proxies, but I work at home and I don't have a proxy.

Below is a couple of screenshots of my console with npm errors:
[image]

[image]

Maybe someone has already encountered that problem and knows how to solve it?

PS: I've read one guy saying that I just need to wait a bit and that npm servers might just be down, but it's already been for 2 days and I can't use npm:(

I hope someone might help)

Comment: Can you ping registry.npmjs.org?

Comment: Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows

Comment: @B3rn475 http://registry.npmjs.org/ works absolutely fine in my browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ETIMEDOUT Error while installing node packages on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bidhan, the command `npm config delete proxy` solved the issue.