# node-fetch connect ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I am trying to get 200 status code in response, but as a result it's ETIMEDOUT.
I can't understand, how is it possible that I can grab successful response via **postman**, but same via **node-fetch** responding with ETIMEDOUT always.
Here is an example of code:

```
const Resource = {
  get: cb => {
    fetch('https://example.com', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: {...some body...},
    }).then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200) cb(`Status: ${res.status}, ${res.statusText}`)
      return res.text()
    }).then(data => {
        cb(null, data)
      }).catch((err) => {
       console.log('ERROR: ', err)
      })
  }
}
```

and here is response:

`ERROR:  { FetchError: request to https://example.com failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\projects\DSSRQ\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1393:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  message: 'request to https://example.com failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT' }`

Comment: Are you actually having http or https as protocol?

Comment: this one is covered by https

Comment: your target host is using what protocol? http or https?

Comment: my target host is using https protocol

Comment: I am doing in on my local nodejs environment.
I've tried using cross-fetch lib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch) with default example of fetching data and got the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm doesn't download packages (connect ETIMEDOUT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736556/npm-doesnt-download-packages-connect-etimedout)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it was because of the proxy limitation.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: Yes sure.
The main problem was in proxy restrictions by company in which I was working.
In this case you just need to configure your proxy config file with the domain and passwords for being able to run it.
At leas it was my solution.