# npm not working - ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, npm

I can't install some npm modules. some modules are installed normally and others gives the below error.

I am not using any proxy.

This is the error message :

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 185.31.**.***80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Comment: If you are not using a proxy, you maybe left some proxy configurations (either env proxy variables or npm proxy variables). Check if they exist and delete them if they do

Comment: npm config get proxy

gives me null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)