# Not able to install package via npm

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-live-server

I am trying to install live-server via npm but getting this instead:

[image: Code Error]

I tried resetting registry to http and both proxy and https-proxy are null.

Comment: It's most likely that npm could be having network issues, have you tried to ping that IP address? Any investigation of your own?

Comment: @EvanDarwin  - I tried :

C:\Users\hchowdha>ping  151.101.72.162

Pinging 151.101.72.162 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.XXX.XX.X: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.XXX.XX.X: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.XXX.XX.X: Destination host unreachable.

Not sure what can possibly be the reason, firewall?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can safely close this question, as it's vague and the issue seems to be on your side.

Comment: Duplicate? Does [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515#28818172](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515#28818172) solve your issue?