# NPM ETIMEDOUT Error while installing React

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, npm-install

I am executing following command on Windows:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

However I am getting following error:

> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
>   npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
>   npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
>   npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
>   npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>   npm ERR! network
>   npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\faizanmubasher\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-20T13_22_23_493Z-debug.log

Though I have properly set the proxy configurations:

```
npm config set http-proxy username:password@proxyip:port -g

npm config set proxy username:password@proxyip:port -g

npm config set https-proxy username:password@proxyip:port -g
```

Also tried this:

```
npm --proxy username:password@proxyip:port\ install -g create-react-app
```

- [Is there a way to make npm install (the command) to work behind
  proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559648/is-there-a-way-to-make-npm-install-the-command-to-work-behind-proxy)
- [NPM Behind A Proxy Server](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/npm-behind-a-proxy-server/19386)
- [How to use NPM Install (The Command) behind Corporate Proxy Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-npm-install-the-command-behind-corporate-proxy-server/)

I am behind corporate proxy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Could it possibly be a problem with NPM and not the package you are trying to install? You could try this:

```
npm config delete proxy
```

Comment: It will delete proxy which is not required here. Cannot delete proxy.

Comment: The problem seems to be with using a proxy and not installing React specifically. I've suggested edits to reflect the subtlety that might help others give you more applicable help.

Comment: Yup exactly, it's proxy problem not related to installation of React.

Comment: So why revert my edits back to saying it's a react installation problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may behind the proxy, Try following methods.

1. You have to set your proxy in the environment variables as this image.
   [windows env setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUD9.png)
2. Then set your proxy using following two commands.

   npm config set proxy http://proxy-server:port

   npm config set https-proxy http://proxy-server:port

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Creating an App

You’ll need to have Node >= 6 on your local development machine (but it’s not required on the server). You can use nvm (macOS/Linux) or nvm-windows to easily switch Node versions between different projects.

To create a new app, you may choose one of the following methods:
npx

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

(npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older npm versions)
npm

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

npm init  is available in npm 6+
Yarn

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

yarn create is available in Yarn 0.25+
Output

Running any of these commands will create a directory called my-app inside the current folder. Inside that directory, it will generate the initial project structure and install the transitive dependencies:

```
my-app ├── README.md ├── node_modules ├── package.json ├── .gitignore ├── public │   ├── favicon.ico │   ├── index.html │   └── manifest.json └── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
```

No configuration or complicated folder structures, just the files you need to build your app. Once the installation is done, you can open your project folder:

```
cd my-app
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to set your proxy in the environment variables as this image.
   [windows env setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUD9.png)
2. Then set your proxy using following two commands.

   npm config set proxy http://proxy-server:port

   npm config set https-proxy http://proxy-server:port

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement all solutions and suggested commands for npm and yarn but it's not resolved.

When I disable my VPN and try to "yarn install, " it will work fine.

If you have a VPN then try to once it disables and executes the "yarn install" command.