# Not able to install cypress on windows 10

Tags: node.js, cypress

[image: screenshot of error log]

Above is the attached picture of the problem I got. I have installed Nodejs and run npm install command to create a package.json file in the cypress folder but was still not able to install it.

Comment: I got the same error..

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

so that npm requests for http url instead of https.

and then try the same npm install command

clear your cache by doing `npm cache clean.`

NOTE **can lead to a security problem since https is not used here. I don't recommend to use this on production.**

If the above mentioned doesn't work:-

1)`ping registry.npmjs.org`

2)I was able to solve this by running the following command:

```
npm config delete proxy 
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

**If this method did not work, disabling your router's firewall would solve  the issue immediately.**

[ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)

Comment: did you clear your cache? can you post your log messages of debug.log?

Comment: i have update my answer, npm config delete proxy would work for you.

Comment: npm config delete proxy 
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to fix,

1. npm config set proxy false
2. npm cache clean --force
3. npm install cypress

Hope it will fix your installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also finding the `npm install cypress` command to be not working.
A workaround is to use `npm install cypress@4.0.1`.