# Can't build expro project

Tags: react-native, frontend, expo

I would like to create react native project using expo
but get fail.... anyone knows how to solve it???

```
request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.16.35:443
```

but using react-native-cli is work for me, not work with expo...

expo init app

```
Choose a template: » blank               a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas
request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.19.35:443
        
FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.19.35:443
            at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:97:14)
            at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
            at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
            at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
            at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)

Comment: I tried to running "npm config delete proxy", but still not work, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I have no idea to run "expo init app"  to create project....

so, I go to https://snack.expo.io/
create and download the project.

then go to the project's root directory.
Then use these commands:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
npm install
expo start
```

It work fine!