# getting error while installing npm packages in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, npm

getting below error while installing npm package chalk in visual studio code

PS C:\sagar\node js training> npm install chalk
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/chalk failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.23.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: PS C:\sagar\node js training> npm install chalk
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/chalk failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.23.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make s

Comment: ure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: "This is a problem related to network connectivity." Try with better internet connection once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I've only gotten that error, when trying to install packages with a very bad internet connection.

I think the only solution is to wait for a better internet connection, and then try again.
I personally just tried to install the package using the 'npm install chalk' and I had no issues.