# showing error while create react app using vite js tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, vite

> i have already checked node and NPM version it is showing properly but while creating react app using Vite.js it is not working

This is the error :

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.24.35:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\91820\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-16T14_30_29_511Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

According to this stackoverflow post:

[ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)

Can you try the following command?

`npm config delete proxy`

Or this commands in order.

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Comment: no i already tried its not working

Comment: And reinstalling node.js?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxEve.png