# npm install always ETIMEOUT can's fix

Tags: node.js, npm

I have spent my whole day on fixing this problem but can't see any light.

My node and npm version is below

[image: Information of node and npm]

And no matter what package I wanna install, it always show
[image]

[image]

[image]

I am sure that I am not in any proxy and I have already lower my node version from 18 to 14,
but the problem still exist!!!!

Could anyone know how to fix this problem help me?
I already tried every way to fix this but can't work.

Comment: Did the problem occur in node v.18, too?

Comment: Yes, that's why I lower to node v.14

Comment: I referred these post
 
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4085
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows

and I thought the problem is for npm version
but it still exist

Comment: I pinged 161.202.62.99 from cmd. The result: `Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)`. I don't know if it will solve the problem, but you may try deleting and re-installing both node and npm.

Comment: Use yarn that might work

Comment: Still can't work even I tried yarn and delete both node and npm.
I am sure my connection just fine.
I truly can't figure out what's the point of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since when did the issue start? Did it occur after you installed any dependency or made any proxy / firewall related configurations?

However you can try one of the following ways to fix this issue

1. Delete node_modules folder and in terminal, write

```
npm install
```

2. Change your nodejs version, either upgrade it or downgrade it
3. Reinstall nodejs
4. Try some other package manager like yarn

Note: When changing your nodejs version, please ensure that your node version is compitable with the npm version

Edit:
If these solutions don't work, the error is most probably caused by network related issues, you can try the following fixes

1. In terminal, reset the registry path of your node package manager

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

2. If you are using your organization's computer, you need to use a proxy, remember to change the proxy url and port as per your organization

```
npm config set proxy http://proxyurl.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxyurl.com:8080
```

3. Instead of local installation, try installing packages globally i.e

```
npm install -g mongoose
```

4. Clear the cache

```
npm cache verify
```

5. Switch your device to some other wifi network and then try installing some npm packages

Comment: Still can't work. I already tried yarn and delete both node and npm.
My node version now is 10.19.0
I am sure my connection just fine. 
I truly can't figure out what's the point of this problem.

Comment: Does this issue occur with other dependencies too? Or with only this dependency you are trying to install? If the issue is with only one dependency, you can manually download it through url and paste the folder in node_modules folder and register the dependency in your package.json file

Comment: Yes, it eccur in all package.
And I just notice when I type npm install.
The message shows 
"rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 9c37d01d8d4d89d1"
Is there any releation between this?

Comment: I tried yarn and the message is "info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying..."But my connection is fine.

Comment: Are you using your personal computer or your office's laptop? Sometimes the office laptops have certain firewall configurations that can cause such errors

Comment: My personal computer. And I just tried turn off all my all firewall. The proble is still exist.

Comment: Really strange, I used to face this issue occasionally when my wifi connection would become slow, Many times fixing my network connection, clearing cache or reinstalling node_modules folder fixed such issues... Nevermind, I've provided some more fixes in the solution, give them a try and let me know the outcome

Comment: The first one works!!! Finally I can install module to my project!