# npm are not working even if i delete the node and install again

Tags: npm, npm-install, etimedout

I can't install new dependencies of our project in my computer.

When i try to reinstall Node.js it does not fix the issue.

```
PS C:\Users\djhay\Desktop\RCI-FRONTEND\richwell_app-frontend> npm install
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react-lifecycles-compat/-/react-lifecycles-compat-3.0.4.tgz failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1123:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\djhay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-21T00_29_18_170Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: The Error is English: `This is a problem related to network connectivity.  In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ETIMEDOUT Error while installing Node packages on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722515/etimedout-error-while-installing-node-packages-on-windows)